# Leaving your WiFi public?

Tags: wireless-networking

How safe is it to leave your wifi public? I have a few computers (Mac, PC) would I be putting those computers on the network in danger? Or would it be a case of just burning bandwidth, and possible use for criminal activities?

Comment: Keeping your WiFi network public is a stupid idea, regardless of where you live.  If you lock your front door, why not lock your network?  Or, better yet, just let me know the next major intersection to you - I'll show you why it's not good to leave your WiFi unencrypted. :)

Comment: So many stories of neighbors surfing child porn on someone else's open network, then the police busting down the door of the wrong person, now you have some explaining to do while you are in Jail.

Comment: The reason to leave it public is a service for our customers (pub), however I wanted to know if it would be ok to use the home wifi.

Comment: Can you clarify the situation more?  Do you want to use a single wifi access point for both pub and home use?

Answer (score 4):

While it sounds like a neighbourly thing to do, it does put yourself at risk.

Use Facebook?  It is trivial to hijack someone's account if you're on the same LAN.  Same with many other online services that you may use.

Also, depending on the laws in your country, you could be held liable for actions taken "from" your network.  So, someone using your network could launch a cyber-attack from your network, download child pornography or perhaps infringe copyrights and you'd be held liable.

Lock it up.

Comment: Just a side note: Yes, it's trivial to hijack somebody's Facebook account if you're on the same LAN, but only if you're **not** using SSL. Facebook.com -> Account Settings -> Account Security -> **Browse Facebook on a secure connection (https) whenever possible**. *That* is the key to not having your Facebook account hijacked, regardless of whether or not you are on an open access point. (Otherwise, I totally agree with your answer!).

Comment: Thanks, but I know this.  The trouble is, not everyone in my household knows this, nor, does every device support it.  And, people on my network may use services other than Facebook (imagine that), many of which may not allow SSL. THIS VERY SITE, for example!

Comment: But just putting a global password even on WPA2 still doesn't protect folks that don't use SSL.  See [How does FaceNiff work? - IT Security - Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4841/how-does-faceniff-work).

Comment: To be more clear, RE: @nealmcb's comment, using WPA2 *will* protect you against *outside* threats.  But, if someone is given access to your Wi-Fi network, they can still capture your wireless traffic.

Comment: @mkoistinen I know; it's not an answer to the question, that's why it's a comment. There's no need to freak out. All I am trying to point out is that, regardless of whether the AP is open or secured, it's best to use SSL/TLS wherever possible. That's why I left the note in parentheses at the end of my comment; I **agree** with your answer. `:)`

Comment: The context here may be a pub with open wifi (though it's not really clear in the question/comment yet).  In that case, the definition of "outsiders" and "insiders" (re: @iszi's comment) is almost totally blurred since all customers get to have the password and are thus "insiders".  But indeed, in a home network where you probably only give the password to folks you trust, WPA2 helps more.  But unless everyone gets their own password, WPA2 doesn't help protect users from each other.

Comment: @nealmcb - The OP doesn't clarify the nature of the network, but it does seem to be a home network.  Still, the topic of free public wifi networks such as coffee shop or community-shared networks is covered here:  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/2214/free-wifi-password-protection-impact-on-security/2253#2253  Also, I think "Hole 196" and others still apply to even WPA2 networks that have per-user authenticators.  It really seems this thread would be better served at Security.SE.

Comment: Oops - I think @iszi is right - anyone with any valid PSK can see the traffic of folks with other PSKs.  See [WPA2 Hole196 Vulnerability](http://www.airtightnetworks.com/WPA2-Hole196)  (Damn - why in the world does IEEE keep botching wireless security?)

Answer (score 1):

It is reasonably unsafe, but it really does depend on what you do. If you tunnel everything through SSH to some safe site or only stick to HTTPS you're reasonably safe (although you could still have someone come in and try to exploit machines on the network). Chances are you don't though, in which case you aren't very safe at all.

See this story for instance: http://money.cnn.com/2010/12/14/technology/firesheep_starbucks/index.htm

Comment: Define "reasonably safe".  Most people set up their home networks as a "trusted" connection, to make home network setups easier (so now you "trust" the attackers machine as well).  Even if you did stick to HTTPS only, an attacker would still see where your internet traffic is traveling through, and the likelyhood of them obtaining relevant login information (or session IDs) through other unencrypted network traffic is almost always high.